# Flask socketIo with gevent not working when debug=False

Tags: flask, raspberry-pi, gevent, flask-socketio

I am running a Flask application on a Raspberry Pi running on a uWSGI server. I am trying to implement a WebSocket protocol with Flask-socketIo combined with gevent & gevent-websocket as specified in the doc.

When I start the app with this line I got no issue, the data is sent to the client thru websocket as expected:

```
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

However if debug is set to False, the emit function is no longer working.

```
def updateSensorsState(sensor):
    print "update"
    socketio.emit('state', json.dumps(sensor))
```

In this case when I press a button updateSensorState(sensor) is called from a GPIO callback. I get update printed in the console and the emit function seems to hang there. If I press the button many time, once in a while the client will receive a queue of message many time later...

Any advice to help me what is going on with my code would be much apreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you also using GPIO when you run in debug mode? I doubt gevent is compatible with that, whatever you do with hardware is likely blocking.

Comment: Yes I run the exact same code with the GPIO. It works in debug and hang when debug is set to False... I also tried with evenlet and same thing happend.

Comment: @Miguel If I run `socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='threading')` and debug=False it also works with long polling.